# DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: webpack:///node_modules/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.js.map

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-chrome-devtools, babeljs

I'm trying to setup a simple html/Js page.

I've installed webpack and babel. I've configured package.json file with the "build" and "start" scripts.

The page works pretty well but the Warning: "DevTools failed to parse SourceMap: webpack:///node_modules/sockjs-client/dist/sockjs.js.map" raises every time I execute the "npm run start" command and I can't debug my code in the Chome Devtools

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "my-proyect",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.js --mode production",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.3",
    "webpack": "^4.42.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

module.exports = {
    // 1
    entry: './src/index.js',

    /////////  BABEL ///////////////
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.(js)$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['babel-loader']
          }
        ]
      },
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['*', '.js']
      },
    ////////////////////////
    ///////// Plugins ///////////
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            title: 'Hello Webpack bundled JavaScript Project',
            template: './src/index.html'
          })
    ],
    // 2
    output: {
      path: __dirname + '/dist',
      publicPath: '/',
      filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    // 3
    devServer: {
      contentBase: './dist'
    }
  };
```

I will really appreciate if someone can guide me through this problem.

Regards.

Answer (score 11):

Adding this to the top of your webpack config file might help:

```
devtool: 'eval-source-map'
```

Comment: It wasn't clear where to add the line. Adding at the topmost (leftmost) level worked for me. That is between that last two curly braces in the OP's webpack.config.js file.

Comment: add at the top if it works and open your web browser devtools search for **Sources**  look for **webpack** if there's a webpack their you know it works

Answer (score 1):

Go to Dev tools settings then go to Preferences. Try to turn off the "Enable Javascript source map" and turn off "Enable CSS source map" and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

> "source-map-loader": "^1.0.0",

add this line to your devDependencies in package.json and run npm install

Answer (score -2):

If they are just unimportant warnings that are bothering you when leaving the console, you can temporarily disable them...

[image]